# Difference initializing of a matrix [C++]

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, boolean, size

I don't get what's the difference between:

```
std::vector< std::vector<bool> > matrix;
```

and

```
bool matrix[n][m];
```

Can I use `.size()` to find rows and cols for both of them?

Thank you.

Comment: *"Can I use .size() to find rows and cols for both of them?"* - no. As for enumerating the differences, I'm undecided if it's too broad or not.

Comment: One is a container, the other is a primitive 2D array.

Comment: It could be a primitive 2D array, It could also be a variable length array, and those buggers require so much back-end weirdness that you can't really call them primitive.

Comment: There are many reasons to use a simple 2D array, though if the asker wants to know about `.size()` this likely isn't one of them

Comment: Woo! Forgot about that one. The other big difference is `vector <vector<whatever>>` is literally a `vector` containing more `vector`s, each with their own dynamically allocated pool of storage. This storage is conceivably scattered throughout memory rather than in one nice block in the case of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a huge difference:

`std::vector< std::vector<bool> > matrix;` - Defines an Object of type `std::vector` that may contain other `std::vector` of `bool`-s.

This uses a container defined by the standard library. It has a vast API with multiple methods that you could use. `matrix.size()` is one of them.

`bool matrix[n][m];` - Defines an array of `n` arrays of `m` bools.

Here, `matrix` is not an Object per-se, but rather a primitive type. You cannot use `matrix.size()` here, but you could use `sizeof(matrix)/sizeof(matrix[0][0])` to get the total number of bools in it.

**My recommendation to you, is use standard library containers as much as possible.**

As some of the comments correctly suggested, you could also use [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of primitive arrays, this is what they're here for after all :)